# Angular5, socket.io-client and Ratchet Websocket failed with HTTP 426 error

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, ratchet

I'm working with an Angular app, that have to communicate with a Websocket server. The ws server is listening on 192.168.1.99:8080 and powered by Ratchet/Websocket (under PHP).

Server is running as expected and allows 'localhost:4200' as trusted client.

On Client side, use a Service that manage connection and message exchange :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

import { Constants } from './../../constants/constants';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {

  private _socket: any;

  constructor() { }

  public sendMessage(messageType: string, message: any){
    this._socket.emit(
      messageType,
      message
    );
  }

  public getMessages(): Observable<any> {
    let observable = new Observable((observer) => {
      this._socket = io(Constants._WS_URL);
      this._socket.on(
        'message',
        (data) => {
          observer.next(data);
        }
      );

      return () => {
        this._socket.disconnect();
      };

    });

    return observable;
  }
}
```

Nothing special... just a copy/paste of existing code.

My component implements onInit and does the following :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // websocket instanciation
    this._wsConn = this.websocketService.getMessages().subscribe((message) 
        => {
          this._messages.push(message);
    });
}
```

When app runs, got :

```
http://192.168.1.99:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8qMAFE 426 (Upgrade header MUST be provided)

(index):1 Failed to load http://192.168.1.99:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8qMAFE: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 426.
```

After hours spent to look for the way to send headers from client, and a lot of coffee, don't find any idea...

Note... Try to communication via Websocket pure Javascript, and all is good :

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.99:8080');
conn.onopen = function(event){
    console.log('Connexion au serveur établie');
}

conn.onmessage = function (event){
    console.log('Message reçu ' + event.data);
}
```

Websocket server logs...

```
/mnt/c/webroot/ws_stestex$ php index.php
Initialise le traitement périodique
Nouvelle connexion : 7036
```

So, my question is... what can i do ? lol...

Well.. I change the service method to :

```
      this._socket = io('ws://192.168.1.99:8080', {
    transportOptions: {
      polling: {
        extraHeaders: {
          'x-clientid': 'saintesaintex',
          'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13'
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Then i got a 405 HTTP error... Can someone tell me the correct headers ?

Note 2 : when i inspect the network console, see that it's not the ws protocol used but http...

Comment: Socket.io does some handshaking over http/xhr before going ws. `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` means there is none, so seems a problem with the server config..

Comment: Try something like `var io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});` on server?

Comment: Finally, i use native websocket object to manage communication between client and server. Thx for all, and your answers was usefull.

Comment: Gj. Sometimes it's just better to DIY :)